# For a given Gaussian vector, which rectangular parallelepiped with unit volum has the largest probability?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a centered Gaussian vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Gamma$ its covariance matrix. We assume that diagonal coefficients of $\Gamma$ are all equal to 1. 
We are looking for a rectangular parallelepiped $[-a^*_1,a^*_1]\times\dots\times[-a^*_n,a^*_n]$ with a volume equal to 1 such that
$$\mathbb{P}(X\in [-a^*_1,a^*_1]\times\dots\times[-a^*_n,a^*_n])\ge  \mathbb{P}(X\in [-a_1,a_1]\times\dots\times[-a_n,a_n]),$$
where $[-a_1,a_1]\times\dots\times[-a_n,a_n]$ is any rectangular parallelepiped with a volume equal to 1.

Comment: Here is a related question that I answered partially: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Which_rectangular_parallelepiped_with_minimal_volume_contains_the_values_of_a_Gaussian_RV#view=587fd19996b7e46a7546a653. I think the solution does not have a closed form even in two dimensions.